# .htaccess errors in WordPress: Rewrite Engine not allowed here

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks, xampp

I'm really fed up. I've tried everything to get my pretty permalinks, but I still end up with either 500 or object not found messages. I am still trying to get it working in a local environment. I have Override set to all in my `http.conf` file and my `http-xammp.conf` file, FollowSymLinks in place and here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?file_name=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ $1$4?$2=$3 [QSA,N]
RewriteCond $1 !.+\.xyz$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)$ $1.xyz [L]

# END WordPress
```

but I still end up with errors! I'm new to the whole htaccess thing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I'm getting now is:

> "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/wordpress/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here, referer:     http://www.mydomain.com/xampp/wordpress/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"

but I'm an administrator and I have full control? Any thoughts?

Comment: I see you have created a number of tag wikis today. **Please** add a link to the source when copying and pasting text verbatim, otherwise you are plagiarizing the text. See: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1394444#./1394444?&_suid=1359139085703017991570232587917.

Comment: Not based on the example of the post I provided, or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1394533#./1394533?&_suid=1359139049062007484664430530241), you didn't. If you copy text, please [cite it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79002/148949)

Comment: please re-review my semantics one i have included the reference

Comment: I am citing my references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting means that the proper override isn't turned on. Htaccess files "override" settings defined by the config files, and the `AllowOverride` directive in the config files determine what type of settings can be overridden by htaccess files. As you can see [in the Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) there's a listing for each directive for **Override**, that means you need to set that in the config.

Somewhere in your xampp config files you should see a `AllowOverride` directive. You can either add `FileInfo` to that list, or you can change it to `All`:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

or

```
AllowOverride All
```

This should allow you to use mod_rewrite directives in your htaccess files.

---

EDIT:

> where should i put it? i put allow override everywhere

Take a look at the [Apache docs for `AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride), you need to put it in a `<Directory>` container. So something like this:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/xampp/wordpress">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

You *have* to make sure that the "/path/to/your/xampp/wordpress" is the **absolute physical file path** where your htaccess file is, and not the *URI path* (the path you'd see in, say, the URL). This means your htaccess file would be in `/path/to/your/xampp/wordpress/.htaccess`.

Comment: @Rachel have you restarted the server? Are you sure there is no other AllowOverride directive elsewhere in the server config?

Comment: yes! i also reinstalled wordpress and xammp and re-cobfigured the files! nothing seems to work!

Comment: @RachelGallen Are you sure the `AllowOverride` is inside a `<Directory>` container that points to the directory that the htaccess file is in (or a parent directory)?

Comment: this is my current setting for my directory <Directory "C:/xammp/htdocs/wordpress"/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory> should i remove the quotes?

Comment: @RachelGallen No, but that doesn't look like the directory that your htaccess file is in. The error that you posted says this: `C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/wordpress/.htaccess` which isn't `C:/xammp/htdocs/wordpress`, so you haven't turned on the correct override for the htaccess file that is causing the error.

Comment: sorry yeah that is what i have in the directory now and i still have problems

Comment: @RachelGallen you have it without the `.htaccess` part right? (because that's not a directory)

Comment: yes of course.. just with the extra xampp in the middle after htdocs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22630/discussion-between-rachel-gallen-and-jon-lin)

Comment: i reinstalled wordpress again and created a new database and changed the permalinks while the pages were still drafts and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here will be that you have the folder in the `htdocs/xampp/` folder. If I remember correctly XAMPP has this folder set up in a certain way and that is likely to cause the problem. Move the `wordpress` folder into your `htdocs` folder and it should work as expected

Comment: i have since resolved this issue but thanks for your answer. +1